# Trouble trying to position Image on Container

Tags: flutter

I just don't know what I'm doing wrong here. The idea is to stack a Network image on a Container that is immediately underneath the AppBar. The trouble is that the Image seems to be cropped or clipped or however you might want to put it once I try positioning it. The code for the same is below:

Screenshot
[image]

main.dart

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey
      ),
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

main_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './widgets/app_bar.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(63, 64, 65, 1),
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.orange),
        title: Text('Cheese Chicken Burger'),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          CustomAppBar(),    //The widget throwing the problem
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

custom_app_bar.dart(This is the widget where all the stacking happens)

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Column(
      children: [
        Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 150,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(120),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(120)
                    ),
                    boxShadow: const [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          spreadRadius: 40,
                          blurRadius: 60,
                          offset: Offset(5, 10)
                      )
                    ]
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 100,
                right: 0,
                left: 0,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 150,
                  height: 150,
                  child: Image.network('https://www.foodrepublic.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/033_FR11785.jpg'),
                ),
              )
            ]
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me fix this? This is what I'm looking for

[image]

Comment: Can you include an attachment, what are you trying to archive ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh The question is now updated with the screenshot

Comment: if I'm not wrong, it is using `Stack`  on scaffold's body.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Yes Sir. It is. Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is some solution with some question for what do you want exactly.
Inside your stack, the container determines your stack height. Let's get a look:
I set the color to amber.

[image]

Your height 150. If we change it to 250, we'll see this.

[image]

It's just because of your `Positioned` widget. You have set your `top` value to 100.

If you try to set your `top` value to 10 or 0. You'll see this:

[image]

For stack, your first container will specify your stack height.

Did I understand your ask ?

[UPDATED CODES]
Container:

```
Container(
                  height: 150, // You can set your stack height with this line
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(120),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(120)),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            spreadRadius: 40,
                            blurRadius: 60,
                            offset: Offset(5, 10))
                      ]),
                ),
```

Positioned Widget:

```
Positioned(
                  top: 10, // You can change this line.
                  right: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 150,
                    height: 150,
                    child: Image.network('put your image url here'),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Yes you did. But do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: I already added the solution but I'll add some codes for you.

Comment: But I actually need it Stacked on the edge of the Container.

Comment: Check out the answer again please. I updated it.

Comment: If you want it to be at the edge you can set some value for ```left``` or ```right``` parameters. If you set these values 0, it will be located at the middle of stack. So then, just use only one side (I mean left or right) to set it at where do you want it exactly.

Comment: The question is now updated with the screenshot

Comment: Added a new answer.

Comment: I don't see the solution. Are you sure you've posted it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to make it like this ?

[image]

[CODES]

```
 Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 300, // this will be your stack height
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(120),
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(120)),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              spreadRadius: 40,
                              blurRadius: 60,
                              offset: Offset(5, 10))
                        ]),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 60,
                  right: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 150,
                    height: 150,
                    child: Image.network(
                        'put your image urls'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

First container specify your stack height. You can change it from there.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for

Comment: Do you know what changes I need to make?

Comment: Good luck, thank you.

Comment: So I start the widget with a stack instead of a column right?

Comment: It's up to you. If you want to add some widget after stack you can start with column but if you don't want, remove the column. It will work perfectly.

Comment: You've just saved my job in a way.  Cheers!!!!

Comment: haha Thank you sir.